# sa can't ALTER USER in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run an `alter user` command as `sa` in SQL Server:

```
ALTER USER MyAppDemoAdmin2 WITH LOGIN = MyAppDemoAdmin2
```

However when I do so I get this error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot alter the user 'MyAppDemoAdmin2', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I see that the user does exist in the user list, so I must not have permission - but I'm logged in as `sa`! How is that possible? How can I get permission to alter the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are database specific, you will need to be in the correct database context to alter the user. Check which context you are in by:

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

Change your context to the appropriate database with:

```
USE [database]
```